# My tezos are baking. Now what?

Tags: baking

I am not a speculator. I am genuinely interested in the concept and success of the Tezos blockchain. So, I bought some Tezos and delegated them to a baker. Now what? How can I contribute to it, beyond trivial things like promoting it around, or participating in forums like this one (hopefully a positive thing!)?

Comment: Welcome to tezos! I am very happy to see new user like you enthusiastic about tezos. Let me note to you however that tezos stack exchange (TSE) is *not a forum*. Rather it is a domain to ask and answer questions of technical nature about tezos. Social media channels like riot/telegram/reddit are more appropriate for general chat about tezos. I am closing your question for this reason because it is “off-topic” with respect to our editorial rules here but this is by no means a way to discourage you. I would love to see your tech questions in the future!

Comment: @Ezy Thanks. I thought it might be off-topic, by the mere fact that I couldn't find any appropriate tag.